# What exactly happens under the hood after dispatching DiffResult to RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was going through RecyclerView's DiffUtil [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.DiffResult.html#dispatchUpdatesTo(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)).

I understood most of the parts except one thing. It says that after calculating the diff, you do:

```
List oldList = mAdapter.getData();
DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyCallback(oldList, newList));
mAdapter.setData(newList);
result.dispatchUpdatesTo(mAdapter);
```

and says:

> you can swap the list with the new one then dispatch all updates to the RecyclerView.

I've a doubt here. What exactly is happening under the hood here?

If I am already dispatching updates to adapter, won't it arrive at the new data by itself after consuming those updates? Why do I need to set the new data explicitely?

An answer that explains how these updates are dispatched and consumed by Adpater in-depth would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Method `dispatchUpdatesTo(RecyclerView.Adapter)` is actually a simple wrapper of `dispatchUpdatesTo(ListUpdateCallback updateCallback)`.

I think [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#658) is self explanatory:

```
public void dispatchUpdatesTo(final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
      dispatchUpdatesTo(new ListUpdateCallback() {
          @Override
          public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
              adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
          }
          @Override
          public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
              adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
          }
          @Override
          public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
              adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
          }
          @Override
          public void onChanged(int position, int count, Object payload) {
              adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count, payload);
          }
      });
}
```

You can see the callbacks only purpose is notifying about updates.

Calculating diff is a read-only operation that leaves both lists unchanged. That's why You need to manually update list inside your adapter.